# HP SATA Hot Plug Activity Light & B120i Array Controller

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, sata, hp-smart-array

The activity rings on both of my hot plug drives rotates continuous (they are in RAID 1 configuration). The drive status on both is solid green.

Is this normal? The iotop command is showing no activity... Total Read/Write zero B/s.

Edit: However, I'm not sure if I'm using that command correctly. Just SSH'd while I had iotop on, it didn't pick up a file write...

Any advice would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether there's read or write activity, the drives are still online and *spinning*!

*Edit: This may just be a function of using the Dynamic Smart Array driver (`hpvsa` module).*

HP explains the [drive functions here](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/mostViewedDisplay?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_efb5c0793523e51970c8fa22b053ce01=wsrp-navigationalState=docId%253Dmmr_kc-0100747-9%257CdocLocale%253Den_US&javax.portlet.tpst=efb5c0793523e51970c8fa22b053ce01&sp4ts.oid=5177961&ac.admitted=1402332639515.876444892.492883150).

[image]

[image]

Please also see HP's video detailing their [SmartDrive disk carrier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYYRAB17f4s).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I browsed through both of those links, and they say the same as my user documentation - i.e., activity ring spins when there is activity... however mine is spinning non-stop - and I don't think I can see any processes doing anything? Is this still normal?

Comment: What model of server are you using? What operating system and version is installed?

Comment: Haha you're not going to like it. DL320e G8 v2. CentOs 6.5.

Comment: Then I suspect the Dynamic Smart Array driver (`hpvsa` module). Recall that this is a bit of a *fakeraid*. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks ewwhite :) You've helped me a lot over the last week.